# angular unique ng-model in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, laravel

So I have an ng-repeat like so:

```
<md-list-item ng-repeat="ride in rides">
    <md-switch aria-label="Join Ride" ng-model="subscribe.sub" ng-change="subscribe(ride.id, subscribe.sub)" flex>
        Join Ride
    /md-switch>
</md-list-item>
```

But, every md-switch has the same model, so when I set it to true in my controller, they all go to true.

So, is there a way to given them an unique ng-model? So I can set them to true in my controller individually?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `ride` or `$index` to distinguish the models. e.g.

```
<md-switch ng-model="ride.sub">
```

Comment: And how do set my md-switch to true in the controller then? By doing: $scope.rides = { ride.sub: true };?

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to set my switch to active in my controller. I can't acces the unique id?

Comment: If you wanted to set one of the rides to true in your controller it would look something like `$scope.rides[0].sub = true`